# c# individual variables for every button

Tags: c#, forms, button

I'm am currently making a little game in windows forms, just for fun.

You have to click on buttons to "damage" them and if they lose enough health they get destroyed.
All of that is working fine but I got about 50 buttons in level one alone and therefore I have got for each button:

3 variables für the RGB Colors,
1 method for the button_click event and
1 timer + method for the health regeneration.

I would like to make a class or edit the button class to give each and every button these properties.

I found this line of code to color every button in the form, but that helps me just not that much. `GetSelfAndChildrenRecursive(this).OfType<Button>().ToList().ForEach(b.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));`

My code for each button:

button class variables:
(variables for button1's RGB colors)

```
public int btn1r = 0;
public int btn1g = 255;
public int btn1b = 0;
```

button1_click event:
(on click, change it's colors from green to red)

```
if (btn1g > 11)
            btn1g = btn1g - 10;
        if (btn1r < 245)
            btn1r = btn1r + 10;
        if (btn1r > 245)
            button1.Visible = false;

        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(btn1r, btn1g, btn1b);
```

timer_tick event:
(changes the color back from red to green over time)

```
if (btn1g > 11 && btn1g < 245)
            btn1g += 2;
        if (btn1r < 245 && btn1r > 11)
            btn1r -= 2;

        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(btn1r, btn1g, btn11b);
```

I know my code is clunky bit for now it works. :D

Here is a screenshot from the game board. As you can see there are many buttons and there will be even more level to play. I really don't what to make hundreds of color variables, timers and event for each button.. ^^
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZBA.png)

Comment: So you'd “like to make a class or edit the button class”. And what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Hey Dour,
I don't know how to give this properties to every Button in form1, or better said in ever button in a group box via a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is missing detail but I'm guessing you want something like:

```
public class GameButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

    public GameButton(string text, Rectangle rect, Color backgroundColor, TimeSpan interval)
        : base()
    {
        Location = rect.Location;
        Size = rect.Size;
        Text = text;
        BackColor = backgroundColor;

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(interval.TotalMilliseconds);
        timer.Tick += Button_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Button_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = ????;
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        timer.Dispose();
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Inside your game logic you'll do something like:

```
 gb = new GameButton("One", new Rectangle(120, 12, 80, 20),
      new Color(???), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));
 this.Controls.Add(gb);
```

Then to get rid of the game button:

```
this.Controls.Remove(gb);
gb.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks Dour!
I will try to work with that from now on. Didn't know you could make child class with controls, that's a huge help! :)